# Brand logo in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know I can use android:logo in the manifest file to make my brand logo prominent in the action bar of my Android app. But the logo ends up being only as big as the action bar icon.

Are there any dimension guidelines so that I can have a wide action bar logo?

Comment: What is the current size of your logo ??
try 64 x 64

Comment: It's hi-res, Web quality

Comment: 64x64? For all densities?

Comment: No.. Just try this size for logo first

Comment: That didn't work either